# Return values from recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Could someone please help me with the recursion code below?

Given an input array and a target, I want to return a boolean true for any nonempty subset which sums up to the target value. I am confused about how to return the correct boolean value from recursion.

In my approach below, I am summing up all the possible combinations of a non-empty sub-set and want to return True to the calling function if any of the non-empty subsets equals the target value. The issue is, due to the multiple recursive call stacks, the correct/expected value for the boolean for a sub-set gets overwritten by the subsequent/remaining recursive call stacks. Is there a work-around for this issue? Or do I use brute force? where-in I store all the possible boolean values for each sub-set combination in a list and return true if atleast one value in the list is a boolean True?

```
public class RecursionPossibleToAchieveTargetSum {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {

        long[] arr = {4,8};
        long k = 4;  
        boolean flag = false;

        if (arr.length > 0 )
            flag = recursionHelper(arr,0,new long[arr.length],0, k);

        System.out.println(flag); 
    }

    public static Boolean recursionHelper(long[] arr, int spos, long[] temp, int tempIndex, long target) {
        if ( spos == arr.length ) {
            return (recursiveAddition(temp, temp.length - 1) == target);
        }

        recursionHelper(arr, spos + 1, temp, tempIndex, target );
        temp[tempIndex] = arr[spos];
        return recursionHelper(arr, spos + 1, temp, tempIndex + 1, target);
    }

    public static long recursiveAddition(long[] arr, int spos) {
        if ( spos == 0 ) {
            return arr[spos];
        } else {
            return arr[spos]  + recursiveAddition(arr, spos-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for recursionHelper?

Comment: It's below the main function. The function name got truncated while copy-paste of code from the IDE. It's given below:                                                                   public static Boolean recursionHelper(long[] arr, int spos, long[] temp, int tempIndex, long target) {
        if ( spos == arr.length ) {
            return (recursiveAddition(temp, temp.length - 1) == target);
        }

        recursionHelper(arr, spos + 1, temp, tempIndex, target );
        temp[tempIndex] = arr[spos];
        return recursionHelper(arr, spos + 1, temp, tempIndex + 1, target);
    }

Comment: basically, the function name "targetSum" is actually, "recursionHelper". It was a typo on my part while editing and formating the code.

Comment: @maverickcoder welcome to stack overflow. It helps / saves time for anyone looking if you edit that method in your question instead of adding to the comments.

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo in my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a List<long[]> to save all the subsets that add up to the target. I also cleaned up the recursion a bit. You can check the size of this result list with "result.size() > 0" and print that boolean. You can also print each array of subsets to know which ones there are.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecursionPossibleToAchieveTargetSum {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {

        long[] arr = {1,2,4,1,3,5};
        long target = 8;
        List<long[]> result = new ArrayList<long[]>();

        if (arr.length > 0 ) {
            result = recursionHelper(arr, target);
        }
        System.out.println(result.size() > 0);
        for(long[] l : result) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
        }
    }

    public static List<long[]> recursionHelper(long[] arr, long target) {
        List<long[]> result = new ArrayList<long[]>();
        if (arr.length == 0) return result;

        for(int j = arr.length; j > 0; --j) {
            long nextsom = recursiveAddition(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, j));
            if (nextsom == target) result.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, j));
        }
        result.addAll(recursionHelper(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), target));
        return result;
    }

    public static long recursiveAddition(long[] arr) {
        if ( arr.length == 1 ) return arr[0];
        return arr[0]  + recursiveAddition(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length));
    }
}
```

Example output with `arr = {1,2,4,1,3,5}` and `target = 8`:

```
true
[1, 2, 4, 1]
[4, 1, 3]
[3, 5]
```